# NHibernate: how to do lookup a specific date in Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

How I can lookup a specific date in Nhibernate?

I'm currently using this to lookup one day's order.

```
 ICriteria criteria = SessionManager.CurrentSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Order))
            .Add(Expression.Between("DateCreated", date.Date.AddDays(-1), date.Date.AddDays(1)))
            .AddOrder(NHibernate.Criterion.Order.Desc("OrderID"));
```

I tried the following code, but they did bring the data for me.

```
Expression.Eq("DateCreated", date)

Expression.Like("DateCreated", date)
```

**Note:**
The pass in date value will be like this `2010-04-03 00:00:00`,

The actual date value in the database will be like this `2010-03-13 11:17:16.000`

Can anyone let me know how to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Just a wild guess, you could try: Expression.Like("DateCreated", date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd%");

Comment: Hi Michael, I have tried this. The data type does not match.

Answer (score 1):

Since your database field has date and time information, querying for a single date will have to use between or greater than / less than. It's not clear from your question which query isn't working, but the second example using `Expression` will not work because the time portion does not match the time portion of the database record.